# How to increase the memory for a Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, memory, oracle-12c

I need to increase the memory for a Oracle database temporary. What steps should I consider?

Oracle 12c

`SHOW PARAMETER TARGET:`

```
archive_lag_target                   integer     0
db_big_table_cache_percent_target    string      0
db_flashback_retention_target        integer     1440
fast_start_io_target                 integer     0
fast_start_mttr_target               integer     0
memory_max_target                    big integer 20032M
memory_target                        big integer 19008M
parallel_servers_target              integer     192
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 3258M
sga_target                           big integer 9792M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
SQL> create pfile from spfile;

Datei erstellt. /* To make sure I always can go back by booting with pfile */

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET MEMORY_MAX_TARGET= 27000m SCOPE=SPFILE;

 /*MEMORY_MAX_TARGET is static (SCOPE can only be SPFILE) and needs to by higher than the MEMORY_TARGET otherwise database will not boot */

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET MEMORY_TARGET= 24000m SCOPE=MEMORY;

 /*Is dynamic and can be changed within the definded MEMORY_MAX_TARGET  */

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET sga_target=0 SCOPE=MEMORY;

 /*Set SGA to auto*/

SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET pga_aggregate_target=0 SCOPE=MEMORY;

/*Set PGA to auto*/

SQL> SHOW PARAMETER TARGET

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
archive_lag_target                   integer     0
db_big_table_cache_percent_target    string      0
db_flashback_retention_target        integer     1440
fast_start_io_target                 integer     0
fast_start_mttr_target               integer     0
memory_max_target                    big integer 27008M
memory_target                        big integer 24000M
parallel_servers_target              integer     192
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 0
sga_target                           big integer 0
```

If the change should not be temporary I could use SCOPE=BOTH to edit the spfile as well.

Answer (score 0):

The max limit on memory that you have depends on how much physical memory that your server has, whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit and what OS you use. For example with 32 bit Windows the limit might be 2GB of RAM, depending on what version of Windows server you are using and whether or no you have a certain flag set that would allow you to use up to 3GB or RAM. If you are using a newer 64 bit OS, then you would have no practical limit to the size of the SGA. It would only depend on the amount of physical memory. So you should provide the following: 32 bit/64 bit, operating system and version, hardware type including chip set.

Comment: Considering the current memory_target is already almost 19 GB, I think it's safe to assume the OP is on a 64 bit system.